# make: No rule to make target.Eclipse error

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

Eclipse keeps complaining `make: * no rule to make target` when I am trying to compile the code. Here is what it shows:

```
make: *** No rule to make target
 `/Users/SCN/Documents/CMC/Working/flappypig/proj.android/../../../extensions/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.cpp', needed by `        `obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.o'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory ``/Users/himanshuarora/Desktop/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/FlappyBird/proj.android'`
```

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

OK.I fixed it.The obj folder had some wrong paths saved for cocos2d and box2d classes.I deleted its contents and recompiled the code.It worked.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer (+1). Just curious as to why "clean project", which ought to have been your first instinct didn't sort it out.